# TFS Build Failing on System.Windows

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I've been trying to run my build on TFS and I keep getting an error that kills my build. What's strange is that nothing except code change has been done since the issue started (Or at least that I'm aware about). I keep seeing this:

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.WinFx.targets (268): Unknown build error, 'Cannot resolve dependency to assembly 'System.Windows, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' because it has not been preloaded. When using the ReflectionOnly APIs, dependent assemblies must be pre-loaded or loaded on demand through the ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve event.'

I've googled this and the only thing I see is that it's because there's a Silverlight dll being used in a WPF application. My application is a WPF project, but I haven't been able to find any changes being done in any of my projects in my solution in regards to references.

For more information, this project is a branch from the main code. The main development branch runs fine, but for some reason, this build just fails.

Any ideas?

Comment: try identifying which project has the reference and then remove the specific version flag / or update the reference to your current framework, and see if that solves your issue.

Comment: I tried doing this. I checked all the references on the build server and theyre fine. I don't get it. All of my builds are failing now. The only one that's not failing is the main code. Every other build is based on a branched version of the code. And all of this used to work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're referencing the Silverlight version of System.Windows instead of the .NET Framework version.  Have you tried installing Silverlight on the build server or changing the reference of your project to point to the normal .NET Framework version of that assembly (which .NET Framework exists on your build server)?